# Calculating colum on several pandas dataframes optimization

Tags: python, optimization, finance

I have several dataframes (100 actually) containing data of last 20 years of nasdaq stocks (1 dataframes for each stock).

I have to calculate sharpe ratio on first month day.

```
  def calculate(self, dataframes, calculationDates):
        for asset in dataframes:
            asset['Calculate'] = np.where(
                asset.index.isin(calculationDates), 1, 0)
            asset['PerfAverage'] = np.where(asset['Calculate'] == 1,  self.annualPeriod *
                                            asset['PerfPerc'].rolling(self.lookbackPeriodPerf).mean(), np.NaN)
            asset['Volatility'] = np.where(asset['Calculate'] == 1, math.sqrt(
                self.annualPeriod) * asset['PerfPerc'].rolling(self.lookbackPeriodVol).apply(np.std), np.NaN)
            asset['SharpeRatio'] = np.where(asset['Calculate'] == 1, asset['PerfAverage'] / np.power(
                asset['Volatility'], self.volatilityAttenuator), np.NaN)
        return dataframes
```

It works but takes about 3 minutes to calculate all the data.

Is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can easily help you.